# How can I get emacs to tell the difference from when I am writing PHP, HTML, and JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, emacs, syntax-highlighting

When using emacs and writing PHP I sometimes need to put html in there and I would like to see a difference in highlighting from PHP to HTML. Also the same goes for if I am putting JavaScript in say an HTML file, how can I get the syntax highlighting to change?

Comment: "Just a link" makes for a poor answer, but I'm too sleep deprived to do more then point in the general direction of http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes

Answer (score 1):

[nXhtml](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html#summary) is the most comprehensive attempt to deal with this problem (specifically for web development) that I'm aware of.

Comment: How is this installed in Debian?

Comment: Well you can use the "Download Latest nXhtml" link at http://ourcomments.org/cgi-bin/emacsw32-dl-latest.pl and follow the instructions provided, or else use something like el-get (https://github.com/dimitri/el-get, recommended for general elisp library management without depending on OS-specific packages!) el-get has a default recipe for nxhtml. I'm not sure if it's for the same version as the download link above, or a more recent one.

Comment: Thanks. I missed the non-W32 download link at the bottom of the page.